# $scope.$apply return error of undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I run this function in ng-click, but got an error TypeError: undefined is not a function  on this line : `$scope.$apply(function () {`

```
app.controller('MainControl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.add = function(){

    $http({
        url: "php/insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'myId': myId
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.currentId = data;
        });

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});

    $scope.tabs.push({
        "currentId": $scope.currentId
    });

}

    });
```

Comment: Why are you using $scope.$apply right there? It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.$apply()` is not needed here. Move

```
$scope.tabs.push({
        "currentId": $scope.currentId
    });
```

to `success` callback of your http promise

```
app.controller('MainControl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.add = function(){

    $http({
        url: "php/insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'myId': myId
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.currentId = data;
        $scope.tabs.push({
            "currentId": $scope.currentId
        });

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});



}

    });
```